# What is the difference between printf("%s"), printf(s) and fputs?

Tags: c, printf, fputs

```
char s[100]={0};
fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);
```

In the context of the code above, what is the difference between these three?

1. `printf("%s",s);`
2. `printf(s);`
3. `fputs(s,stdout);`

Comment: Did you try reading the manual pages?

Comment: What happens in each case if your string looks like this: `"bad format %s %*d"` ?

Comment: `printf(s);` will interpret `s` and if it contains a `%` sign, unpredictable results will occurr.

Comment: `fputs(str, stdout)` is the same as `puts(str)`, which is simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `printf("%s",s);` correct but printf is a very heavy function and most compilers will actually replace it with puts in the compiler code if the format string ends with '\n'
2. printf(s); very dangerous as the format string may contain `%` and then it will expect another parameters. If it happens it is UB. It also makes your code exploit prone
3. fputs(s,stdout); OK. Not as heavy as printf but will add the new line

Comment: I would only add that `puts()` adds a newline

Comment: fputs doesn't add a newline though?

Answer (score 2):

#2 Should **NEVER** be used. I won't even write it here.  An evil input can do very bad things in your system by introducing special characters.  New versions of `gcc` warn you about this bug.

The difference between
`printf("%s", s);`
and
`puts(s)`
is that `puts` will add a newline, just like if you called
`printf("%s\n", s);`

Comment: Easy. With string literal there is no danger. Only if the format string is not the string literal

Comment: Yes, it is safe in that case, but I see no reason to write a string literal that way just to save a few characters.  If in the future, someone changes `s` to be variable, that would introduce a bug unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by other comments and answers, do not try the second option. Also, the third one is quite lighter than the first one.

However, I still prefer the first option (`printf()` function) because it allows you to have a formatted string, which means you can print out almost any data type using this function, whereas the function `fputs` only accept strings. So in most cases, you will have to format the string first (maybe using `sprintf()`) before passing it to the function !